# How to enable message button in CallKit screen

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

Does anybody knows how to show or enable message button in CallKit screen when user receives incoming call?
I tried to search multiple sources but I couldn't find any information about this topic.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4qSz.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

message button can be appeared if support SiriKit to send message. (add INSendMessageIntent to intent's info.plist)